# Print WPF canvas and grid to single A4 Page

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, canvas, printing

I have a canvas to which I add various UIElements at runtime and I need to be able to print it to a single A4 page with some additional text in a grid along the bottom.

I can print the canvas using this code.

```
Dim printdlg = New PrintDialog
If printdlg.ShowDialog() Then printdlg.PrintVisual(GraphCanvas, "My Result")
```

I just need to also print a grid underneath and ideally scale it all to 1 page.

I've seen FlowDocuments but can't figure out how to add my canvas to it.

Any help appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 0):

You have several questions wrapped up in one here. To get started, I'll focus on what seems to be the main question - how to add a `Canvas` to a `FlowDocument`.

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
. . .
public FlowDocument ToFlowDocument(Canvas canvas)
{
    var flowdoc = new FlowDocument();
    var newCanvas = new Canvas();

    // UI elements can only have one instance per UI.
    // Move from canvas to flowdoc here.
    for (int i = 0; i < canvas.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        var child = canvas.Children[i];
        canvas.Children.Remove(child);

        newCanvas.Children.Add(child);
    }

    var container = new BlockUIContainer(newCanvas);
    flowdoc.Blocks.Add(container);
    return flowdoc;
}
```

The trickiest part is really just remembering that the UI can only have one instance of each UIElement.